# Minimal Linux distribution

Tags: linux, unix

I am just finishing reading the Tanenbaum operating systems book where he introduces the Minix OS. I would like to go the next step towards studying the inner parts of an OS....

What is the smallest linux/linux distribution I can strip down the most, whilst still having driver support for common Intel networking/ethernet drivers (for my desktop)?

Things like application manager, games, desktop themes etc etc (all the bloated code) I will not need because I would like to try and write my own barebone OS.

I would use Minix and build upwards (in contrast to stripping Linux down), but I'm worried its a little too basic and will be hard to get drivers as it is quite old now.....

Comment: Minix is by no means old; it's actually actively developed. that, however, won't help you with drivers, as it's not really an OS that anyone uses practically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're quite confusing Linux, the kernel, with GNU/Linux distributions, that come with the kernel (which, besides some patches and the configuration, is always the same) and a lot of programs. So, there is no "stripping down" required when starting with the kernel itself.

You might be interested in http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/ – A guide to building your own Linux from scratch.

Comment: Hi dominikh, so if I visited kernel.org that will give me the bare minimum to get an OS started? Thats the core of Ubuntu, Fedora, Red Hat etc,  but then all the stuff I dont want is added to them, which makes them Ubuntu, Fedora, Red Hat etc?

Comment: @user997112 Go through the guide, it will teach you all the stuff you need to know. Because right now, you are just completely confused. The stuff you need to know, is way beyond what can be explained here. The http://linuxfromscratch.org guide will give you all the information you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

And Linux From Scratch which mentioned here ain't a real distro but a way to tell you how to build a usable operating system based on a Linux kernel.

I highly recommend you to play with gentoo first and its official documentation will help you a lot to get to the bottom of how a Linux distro was made up and works.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can try somethings from [8 of the best tiny Linux distros](http://www.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/8-of-the-best-tiny-linux-distros-683552).
Another suggestion is to look to [FreeRTOS](http://www.freertos.org/).